# Resolve two GraphQL schema fields using one endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, graphql, apollo

There's a situation where there are two possible types to fill `data` property. I have made a `union` type for that (`ComponentItem`) to determine which field needs to be returned. The first schema (`ComponentItem1`) should just be a hardcoded list but the second one (`ComponentItem2`) is more dynamic where it gets a `searchTerm` from query and it actually calls an endpoint to fill the `list` and also has `hasNextPage` property.

Here are the schemas I made:

```
type Component {
  id
  title
  data: ComponentItem
}
```

```
union ComponentItem = ComponentItem1 | ComponentItem2
```

```
type ComponentItem1 {
    list: [List!]!
}

type ComponentItem2 {
    hasNextPage: Boolean;
    list: [List!]!
}
```

In the resolver I'm resolving the union type in order to generate proper `__typename`:

```
const resolver: {
    ComponentItem: {
        __resolveType(object) {
            if(object.searchTerm){
               return "ComponentItem2"
            }
            return "ComponentItem1"
        },
    },
}
```

What I'm currently doing is to resolve the `list` and `hasNextPage` individually but in this scenario I'm sending the request to the same endpoint twice.

```
const resolver = {
   ...resolver,
   ComponentItem2: {
     list: async (root, __, context) => {
         const result = await fetch('search-endpoint')
         return result?.items || []
     }
     hasNextPage: async (root, __, context) => {
         const result = await fetch('search-endpoint')
         return result?.hasNextPage || false
     }

   }
   
}
```

My question is how it is possible to share that result in another field resolver (Other than using "context"). Or if there's any better way to handle this situation let me know.

Comment: You can call the endpoint in the `Component.data` resolver. Can you share that code as well, please?

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to lazy load that query in the context. Each resolver would call that property on the context, but only the first would actually execute it.